# Insulation around the pipe outside of a kitchen exhaust

Tags: insulation, exhaust-vent

**Context**

I have a kitchen exhaust which works well enough, this question is about insulation. Last winter was quite a cold one for where I live, and I felt a nice fall of cold air coming from there. I want to fix this before next winter. I have no problem about ventilation in the house, so this pipe can be completely closed when not in use.

The pipe itself will receive an anti wind valve (not sure how it's called in English - but it is something between the pipe and the grid outside, it has 2 wings with a light spring. When the exhaust is on, the wings are open, when it's off the springs will close the wings).

**Actual question**

My question is what to do around the pipe, on the outside. There is quite a hole in the bricks:

- between the pipe and the bricks, I can easily pass 2 or 3 fingers, for about 6cm (2 inches+) deep
- further down there's some isolation, but I can still pass one finger between the pipe and the isolation.

[image: outside of exhaust pipe]

I could of course just fill the hole with insulation foam, but I'm not sure that it's smart (then the pipe will be stuck there and cannot be moved any more).

I could put a snug layer of glass wool (or equivalent, suggestion welcome). It feels better, at least it can be removed, but I'm worried about possible rain going there. Would it be an issue?

What would be the smartest way forward?

Update: There is a grid on top, held in place by screws and the 4 holes that can be seen. I removed it for the picture. This grid does next to nothing for insulation.

Comment: *Egad.* Is that (as it appears to be) a **flexible plastic duct carrying kitchen exhaust?** I don't know about your location, but in my area that would be a code violation (kitchen ducts get greasy, and sometimes catch fire, and should be smooth, cleanable, and solid metal because of those issues.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal At first, I thought that egad was an insulation brand recommendation. Well, I learned a new word today. But yeah, it's what you said. My house is about 30 years old in the Netherlands. I'll check your point.

Comment: I couldn't find anything (except that it is not advised indeed). In my case the exhaust is against the wall, so the duct must be 30 cm long max, so maybe it's OK.

Comment: Besides the other problems, having an elbow pointing down will reduce some cold air coming in.  Cold air sinks.  At one time there might have been a type of panel/housing with outlet for the exhaust pipe.  Seems like it was fitted onto the wall with those four holes, two orange plastic pieces look like screw anchors.